# Select last complete block of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have data similar to

```
ID    Position
1     1           
2     2           
3     3           
4     1           
5     2           
6     3           
7     1           
8     2
```

and I want to select the last set of rows that contain all positions, 1 through 3. By last I mean the set of rows with the highest value in the ID column. The desired result is

```
ID    Position
4     1           
5     2          
6     3
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Wouldn't the last set be 6,7,8? SELECT Position, MAX(ID) FROM table GROUP BY Position.

Comment: Yes but what I want is the last set starting from 1 and ending on 3, other wise I would always just select the last three rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method, which find the last ID where the Position is 3, and gets the two rows preceding that. This assumes Position is sequential as it is in the sample data.

```
declare @table table (ID int identity(1,1), Position int)
insert into @table
values
(1),(2),(3),(1),(2),(3),(1),(2)

select top 3 
*
from @table
where ID <=(
            select max(ID)
            from @table
            where Position = 3)
order by ID desc
```

Or you could do this with an `AND` in your `WHERE` clause. I would store the ID as a variable so you only have to do the aggregation once though.

```
declare @id int = ( select max(ID)
                    from @table
                    where Position = 3)
select *
from @table
where ID <= @id
  and ID >= @id - 2
order by ID
```

Comment: Thank you! As a follow up question, how can I calculate the average of these specific values?

Comment: Of which values? This would be a different question so I'd open up a new one. It'd be answered quickly i'm certain @KevinLópez

Comment: Of the outputted values, I would open up a new question but I'm not allowed to post that often

Comment: `avg()` like `avg(ID)` i'm guessing is what you mean

Comment: well theres a column i didnt include but i want the average value of that column for the rows that are outputted

Comment: @KevinLópez that's why I'd open a new question, with sample data and expected output.

Comment: I'll do that once I can post again

Comment: @scsimon.. tell me what is your result after insert `(9,2)` and `(10,3)`..??

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish read my answer. I stated this assumes position is sequential. Your sample data negates this.

Comment: @scsimon... please try this set of inputs.. `insert into @table
values
(1),(2),(3),(1),(2),(3),(1),(2),(2),(3)`

Comment: Perhaps my explanation wasn’t good enough. My answer assumes that the position is sequential unless it resets. Thus it will always be 1,2,3 or rest to 1. For example 1,1,2,1,2,3. This is what I meant by sequential. There are methods to handle your sample but it doesn’t match the pattern of the original post